# Textbox not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having some trouble narrowing down whats causing my text box not to work in IE. When loading in IE, the area where the textbox should be is blank. I know its being caused by the CSS being applied. This is the CSS class.

```
.field.m {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Although, when I switch the CSS to these properties, from a text box on another page that works, it populates and is not blank

```
.field.m {
width: 65%;
 height: 40px;
margin-right: 3%;
float: left;
border: 0px solid #000;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .31), inset 0 2px 9px -1px          rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 0 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .09), 0 1px 0 0 hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .13);
-webkit-transition: background-color 300ms ease, box-shadow 300ms ease;
transition: background-color 300ms ease, box-shadow 300ms ease;
color: #222222;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

I am wondering why the first one does not appear in IE but the second one does, and what I can do to fix my original.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Make sure the textbox is not overriding any other css class, id, tag or inline css. Use browser's Inspect Element to find out.